# How can I determine the IP address of my router

Tags: 12.04, networking, python-2.7, nmap

I want determine the ip of my router address by writing a python code. I found this proposal:

```
$ sudo easy_install netifaces

Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Oct  1 2012, 22:04:36)
...
$ ipython
...
In [8]: import netifaces

In [9]: gws=netifaces.gateways()

In [10]: gws

Out[10]:

{2: [('192.168.0.254', 'eth0', True)],
 'default': {2: ('192.168.0.254', 'eth0')}}

In [11]: gws['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][0]

Out[11]: '192.168.0.254'
```

and my result in the terminal:

```
In [1]: import netifaces

In [2]: gws=netifaces.gateways()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/rimeh/Bureau/<ipython-input-2-47b29e25a9b8> in <module>()
----> 1 gws=netifaces.gateways()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gateways'
```

How can help me please, I need help.
thanks.

Comment: I need help  @ Sylvain Pineau

Answer (score 3):

1. Install `netifaces` using `pip`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-pip
   sudo apt-get build-dep python-netifaces
   sudo pip install netifaces
   ```
2. To get the gateway ip you can use the following code:

   ```
   $ python 
   Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
   [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> import netifaces
   >>> gws=netifaces.gateways()
   >>> gws['default'].values()[0][0]
   '192.168.1.1'
   >>>
   ```

Comment: `netifaces` has packages available: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=netifaces

Comment: @muru thanks, I know but you need at least netifaces 0.10.0 to call `gateways()` (See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces)

Comment: @SylvainPineau, I did the 1 but I have the same problem:                                                            rimeh@rimeh-PC:~$ python 
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import netifaces
>>> gws=netifaces.gateways()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gateways'

Comment: @muru I installed netifaces but the same problem.