# How can I get the MAC addresses of machines using python-nmap?

Tags: 12.04, networking, python-2.7, nmap

How can I get the MAC addresses of machines using python-nmap?

I'm using python-nmap to scan my local network, I can get the ip of several systems but not their MAC addresses.

How can I get the MAC addresses in the scan results?

```
nm = nmap.PortScanner()    
a=nm.scan(hosts=cidr2, arguments='-sP') 

for k,v in a['scan'].iteritems(): 
        if str(v['status']['state']) == 'up':
                     number_thread += 1
                     print str(v)
             try:    print str(v['addresses']['ipv4']) + ' => ' + str(v['addresses']['mac'])
             except: print str(v['addresses']['ipv4'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the MAC addresses of systems on the same network (my own local network) using the following code.

Moreover **you have to run this code as root** (using `sudo`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import nmap

nm = nmap.PortScanner() 
cidr2='192.168.1.99/24'

a=nm.scan(hosts=cidr2, arguments='-sP') 

for k,v in a['scan'].iteritems(): 
    if str(v['status']['state']) == 'up':
        print str(v)
        try:    print str(v['addresses']['ipv4']) + ' => ' + str(v['addresses']['mac'])
        except: print str(v['addresses']['ipv4'])
```

Source: [is it possible to get the MAC address for machine using nmap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13212187/1154487)

Comment: thnks Sylvain Pineau for your response .I take your code and I try to but I have executed the same result no mac address:
here is the print screen .                                                                    rimeh@rimeh-PC:~$ sudo python mac.py 
[sudo] password for rimeh: 
{'status': {'state': u'up', 'reason': u'localhost-response'}, 'hostname': u'rimeh-PC', 'vendor': {}, 'addresses': {u'ipv4': u'192.168.1.117'}}
192.168.1.117

Comment: 1. change the value of cidr2 to your own ip 2. use an ip in the same network 3. run your script with sudo

Comment: of course i make my own ip but no adress mac

Comment: @kaio: Try to use the ip address of your router (e.g 192.168.1.1/24). I also don't get any MAC add for my localhost

Comment: OK thank you  so much i have the result, thanks a lot :) Sylvain Pineau

Comment: Sylvain Pineau if my ip network is x.x.x.x then ip of my routeur is x.x.x.1

Comment: @kaio. It was just an example, it can be anything.

Comment: but I need to write a method that gives ip my router from my network ip local.To have display mac address if the router ip does not end with one example which other cases.@ Sylvain Pineau

Comment: @kaio the command `route -n` will tell you the ip of your router/gateway

Comment: But I will not use the terminal I must write a code on python to find routeur ip when I have  network ip local @Sylvain Pineau

Comment: @kaio: You can use `subprocess.check_output()` from python or use a dedicated lib (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761829/python-get-default-gateway-for-a-local-interface-ip-address-in-linux)

Comment: ,Can you help me ,when I use  subprocess.check_output() the result is  gws=subprocess.check_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)

Comment: @kaio: Could you please create a new question? comments are not the right place for answers. thanks

Comment: I did a new question @Sylvain Pineau http://askubuntu.com/questions/589205/how-can-i-determine-the-ip-address-of-my-router